# How to perform bulk actions in CQRS?

Tags: cron, cqrs, bulk

I need to perform certain action on multiple entities (cron job) do I run a command in a loop with transaction or it's bad?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine yourself not automating this task. Would you sit behind your computer executing this loop yourself by clicking buttons from a GUI and sending these commands separately?

If so, I think an automated loop executing these commands does nothing different from that.

Comment: Is this yes or no I can't tell